# How to set foreign-domain alias for a Failover Cluster client access point?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

I have a migration scenario with a Failover Cluster file service where I would like to add the alias for the old file server name pointing to the cluster service client access point name.

Using CNAMEs or A-RRs with DNS and creating client access points for the cluster is easy enough, but my trouble is that the Cluster Manager is only allowing for single-label CAP names and seems to only be appending the primary DNS suffix to the name.

So given a deprecated file service called `\\oldserver.olddomain.example.com` and a cluster CAP named `oldserver`, the names the cluster CAP will respond to will be `\\oldserver.clusterdomain.example.com` and `\\oldserver`. I can't seem to be able to get it responding at `\\oldserver.olddomain.example.com`, it is throwing 0x80004005 (unspecified error) upon my access attempts.

The packet trace is showing an SMB2 IoCtl Response packed with *STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED* from the CAP's IP address after my client has established a Tree Connect and has sent the *FSCTL_VALIDATE_NEGOTIATE_INFO* request.

The [*"How to Configure an Alias for a Clustered SMB Share"*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2012/04/08/10291792.aspx) blog post suggests setting an alias using `Set-ClusterParameter. Unfortunately, it is not accepting FQDNs either erroring out with *"The format of the specified network name is invalid"*

I also have already registered SPNs for `oldserver.olddomain.example.com` and `oldserver` to the CAP's domain computer account, so Kerberos should not be a problem.

**Edit:** adding `DisableStrictNameChecking` [to the registry](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660057%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of the cluster nodes unfortunately does not help either.

Comment: I wonder if this has any relation to Strict Name Checking on the cluster members themselves. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660057%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @joeqwerty Failover Clusters work a tad differently - the challenge is to use a single instance of the Server service for multiple differently named File Server cluster resources and isolating the share names between them.  Thus ["scoping" is used](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/01/09/file-share-scoping-in-windows-server-2008-failover-clusters.aspx), tying a resource's shares to a well-defined set of names. I suspect that DisableStrictNameChecking will throw me to the host scope with only the shares of the node hosting the resource visible, but will have a go at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [D'oh!](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/c/c3/D%27oh.jpg/revision/latest).

I should have rebooted my client(s) before testing - this would have helped. It turns out this has not been about foreign domains at all, just a temporary SMB signature verification issue.

[*Windows 8<sup>1</sup>: SMB reconnections fail with “Invalid Signature” upon server upgrade to SMB 3.0<sup>2</sup>*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2756452):

> 1. The Windows 8 client maps a share on a server with the SMB 2.1 dialect, the server’s highest dialect.
>
> Example using Powershell command: New-SmbMapping -LocalPath Y:
>   -RemotePath \FileServer\Share
>
> 2. The server disconnects TCP and its software is upgraded to a version that supports SMB 3.0.
> 3. The client negotiates SMB 3.0 dialect, the newest server’s highest dialect, and attempts re-connecting to the same share.
> 4. The server fails to validate the signature the client sent in the IOCTL FSCTL_VALIDATE_NEGOTIATE_INFO. The server returns an error
>      ACCESS_DENIED to the client.
>
> [...]
>
> A possible workaround is to have the Windows 8 client disconnect and delete that connection/session before it can re-establish a new connection. This requires un-mapping the drive (and wait for about 20 seconds for the client to cleanup data related to that connection entry) and then remap it again.
>
> A client reboot the client will also achieve the same result but it is not required.

---

<sup>1</sup>: I have this
<sup>2</sup>: I have done this